# Toggle Between Three State With JToggleButton

Tags: java, eclipse, togglebutton, windowbuilder

How can i implement a 3-state toggle button? I'm using eclipse and windowBuilder and i'm coding a program which has to have 3-state buttons. I used JToggleButtons and their two state for two bu can't implement the third state. What can i do?

P.S. I want three icon state.

Comment: Sorry. I pasted my answer in the wrong thread. What was I thinking!! I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can look at the code used by [`com.jidesoft.swing.TristateCheckBox`](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/TristateCheckBox.html):
See [`TristateCheckBox.java`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/com/jidesoft/jide-oss/2.0.4/jide-oss-2.0.4-sources.jar!/com/jidesoft/swing/TristateCheckBox.java?format=ok).

It does inherit from `JToggleButton` and has three different icon states.

```
/**
 * Maintenance tip - There were some tricks to getting this code
 * working:
 * <p/>
 * 1. You have to overwite addMouseListener() to do nothing
 * 2. You have to add a mouse event on mousePressed by calling
 * super.addMouseListener()
 * 3. You have to replace the UIActionMap for the keyboard event
 * "pressed" with your own one.
 * 4. You have to remove the UIActionMap for the keyboard event
 * "released".
 * 5. You have to grab focus when the next state is entered,
 * otherwise clicking on the component won't get the focus.
 * 6. You have to make a TristateDecorator as a button model that
 * wraps the original button model and does state management.
 *
 * @author Dr. Heinz M. Kabutz
 */
public class TristateCheckBox extends JCheckBox {
```

Comment: @ÖmerFarukAK: you mean you don't have access to the source code? Remember, it is a starting point, a code for you to examine and pick the good ideas. jide-oss, JIDE Common Layer (Professional Swing Components, http://java.net/projects/jide-oss/) is a subproject of Javadesktop, was started in January 2011. All I am saying is that this project seems to have already implemented what you are after.

Comment: sorry i couldn't see the link, but you had allready wrote... My fault.

Comment: I couldn't used setState funtion from other class. But setState is public. What can i do?